# Problem with python code to insert csv file into SQL (empty) table

Tags: python, sql

So, I have the folowing code using '{}' as placeholders for the data. but when I checked the table in SQL server...it was full of {}, no data at all! If I use %s or %d, etc. it shows an error and if I use the ? placeholder I get an error still. I've akso tried creating table with VARCHAR data type for all columns but still wont work.

I tried %s and %d with quote marks withoutthem with comas and without...don't know what else to do :(
Here's the code and the respectve errors:

`````
import pyodbc
print('Connecting...')

#Server in my PC:
conn = pyodbc.connect('Trusted_Connection=yes', DRIVER = '{ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server}', SERVER = 'MYPRECIOUS', DATABASE = 'QAStore') 
print('Connected')
cursor = conn.cursor()
print('cursor established')

create_table = '''
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS UFO_GB_1;
CREATE TABLE UFO_GB_1
(Index_No int NOT NULL,
date_time datetime NOT NULL,
city_or_state VARCHAR(100) NULL, 
country_code VARCHAR(20) NULL,
shape VARCHAR (200) NULL,
duration float NULL, 
date_posted date NULL,
comments VARCHAR(700) NULL);
'''
cursor.execute(create_table)
conn.commit()
print('Table created')

SQL_string = '''INSERT INTO QAStore.[dbo].[UFO_GB_1]
([Index_No],[date_time],[city_or_state],[country_code],[shape],[duration],[date_posted],[comments])
VALUES ('?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?');'''

#Open the file as readable, and populate the table in SSMS with correct data cleaning
with open(r'UFO_Observations_1.csv','r') as file:   
    #file.readline() #Use if we want to skip header
    print('File read')
    for line in file:        
        cols = line.split(',')
        result = SQL_string.format(cols[0].replace('ï»¿244', " "), cols[1], cols[2], cols[3], cols[4], cols[5], cols[6], cols[7].replace('&#44', ",")) 
        cursor.execute(SQL_string)
        conn.commit()
conn.close()
print('Table Ready')````



##Using VALUES ('?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?') I get this error

````Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\DATA_ANALYSIS_LEVEL_QA\MODULE_2\Challenge_2\TASK_2\Task2_C2_MY_PC.py", line 99, in <module>
    cursor.execute(SQL_string)
pyodbc.DataError: ('22018', "[22018] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '?' to data type int. (245) (SQLExecDirectW)")````

##With VALUES( %d, %s%s%s %s:%s, %s, %s, %s, %f, %d, %s%s%s ) I get this error:

````Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\DATA_ANALYSIS_LEVEL_QA\MODULE_2\Challenge_2\TASK_2\Task2_C2_MY_PC.py", line 100, in <module>
    cursor.execute(SQL_string)
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'd'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)")````

##Using VALUES ('{}','{}','{}','{}','{}','{}','{}','{}') I get this error

````Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\DATA_ANALYSIS_LEVEL_QA\MODULE_2\Challenge_2\TASK_2\Task2_C2_MY_PC.py", line 102, in <module>
    cursor.execute(SQL_string)
pyodbc.DataError: ('22018', "[22018] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '{}' to data type int. (245) (SQLExecDirectW)")````
`````

Answer (score 0):

You are sending in '?' and '{}' into the first field which is defined as an integer.  Only numbers are allowed in integers.

```
 Index_No int NOT NULL
```

Comment: Yes, I've already tried %d and %s for digits and strings respectively, but I'm still getting the error :(

Comment: Could you please show in your question your code when using %d and %s and the error you get.

Comment: Yes, I kinda did :)  ...I just replace:
 `VALUES ( %d, %s%s%s %s:%s, %s, %s, %s, %f, %d, %s%s%s )`
 but verything else stays the same. I'm not yet very familiar with this editor so I dont know how to insert big code in comment :)